# Elasticsearch lucene query in grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I have Grafana 2.6 and Elasticsearch 1.6.2 as datasource

on each of my documents, I have a field "status" that can have the values "Queued", "Complete"

I would like to graph the number of documents with *status:Queued* on time

here is 1 document:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "e_sdoc",
  "_id": "AVHFTlZiGCWSWOI9Qtj4",
  "_score": 3.2619324,
  "_source": {
    "status": "Queued",
    "update_date": "2015-12-04T00:01:35.589956",
    "md5": "738b67990f820ba28f3c10bc6c8b6ea3",
    "sender": "Someone",
    "type": "0",
    "last_client_update": "2015-11-18T18:13:32.879085",
    "uuid": "a80efd11-8ecc-4ef4-afb3-e8cd75d167ad",
    "name": "Europe",
    "insert_date": "2015-11-18T18:14:34.302295",
    "filesize": 10948809532,
    "is_online": "off",
    "id1": 77841,
    "id2": 53550932
  },
  "fields": {
    "insert_date": [
      1447870474302
    ],
    "update_date": [
      1449187295589
    ],
    "last_client_update": [
      1447870412879
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is: Grafana wants a lucene query to submit to ES
but I have no idea what I should use

Have searched through the official doc, Grafana issues or looked into ES query made by Kibana but I can't find a valid syntax that is working :/

Comment: Can you express the query you want to use in human terms? `status:queued` doesn't work?

Comment: count documents where status:Queued at this moment.

`status:Queued` does not return error but Grafana does not return datapoints on 24h and looking in Kibana I see documents with status:Queud on last 24h

Comment: Note that I wrote `queued` in lowercase, that makes a difference. Can you try?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: in fact, I don't succeed to retrieve any datapoints to Grafana from ES despite the connection is ok. I think something is wrong elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

time field was the problem. it seems there is no timestamp in my documents

edited my Elasticsearch datasource

changed 'Time field name' from `@timestamp` to `update_date`

I have now datapoints !

(see comments for the lucene query)

Comment: Could you share an example of the lucene query you provided? I have a similar use case.

Comment: `status:Queued` this was my lucene query in this case. it consists of  `field: Value`